# Contour integration w/ exponential and cosine functions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am trying to solve the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-\cos(x)}{x}dx$$ using contour integration. However, I do not know where to begin. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it $\frac{e^{-x}-cosx}{x}$?

Comment: @Mark yes, that is correct

Comment: No idea if this will work in this case, but you could try a keyhole contour. Quite often when doing an integral in this way you may need to consider something like $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-z}-e^{iz}}{z}dz$ in order to get convergence of integrals around the circles of radius $r$ and $R$, then take the real part at the end. See here for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_4_%E2%80%93_branch_cuts

Comment: @Pixel I tried that method and did not have success.

Comment: Show that
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-x} - e^{i x}} x dx =
\int_0^{i \infty} \frac {e^{-x} - e^{i x}} x dx =
-\int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-t} - e^{-i t}} t dt,$$
then consider the real parts of the integrals on the lhs and rhs.

Comment: @Maxim Am I using the keyhole contour from Pixel's comment to do this? If not, what contour should I use? When the problem is worked out the integral should equal 0, correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With some research, I developed these approaches: Complex analysis, Laplace transform, and special functions

## 1. Complex Analysis (recommended)

If we were to calculate the following integral

$$\oint_C{e^{-z}-e^{iz}\over z}\mathrm{d}z\equiv\int\limits_{\gamma+C_1+\Gamma+C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z$$

with the contour being

[image: contour]

Since $f(z)$ is analytic on and within the contour, LHS is automatically zero. Now, let's look at RHS (with the $C_1$ part parametrized):

$$
0=\int_{\gamma+\Gamma} f(z)\mathrm{d}z+\int_\varepsilon^R{e^{-t}-e^{it}\over t}\mathrm{d}t+\int_{C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z
$$

Now, let's bring substitution $z=it,\mathrm{d}z=i\mathrm{d}t$ to $\int_{C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z$

$$
\int_{C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z=\int_R^\varepsilon{e^{-it}-e^{-t}\over t}\mathrm{d}t
=\int_\varepsilon^R{e^{-t}-e^{-it}\over t}\mathrm{d}t
$$

As a result, we have

$$
\int_{C_1+C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z
=\int_\varepsilon^R{2e^{-t}-(e^{it}+e^{-it})\over t}\mathrm{d}t
$$

With the Euler's formula $2\cos\theta=e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}$, we obtain

$$
\int_{C_1+C_2}f(z)\mathrm{d}z=2\int_\varepsilon^R{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}\mathrm{d}t
$$

Plugging the result back into our original contour integration equation, we can discover

$$
0=\int_{\gamma+\Gamma}f(z)\mathrm{d}z+2\int_\varepsilon^R{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}\mathrm{d}t
$$

Now, take the limit on both side as $R\to\infty$ and $\varepsilon\to0$:

$$
0=\lim_{(\varepsilon,n)\to(0,\infty)}\int_{\gamma+\Gamma}f(z)\mathrm{d}z+2\int_0^\infty{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}\mathrm{d}t
$$

I think it would be a trivial task to show that the remaining limit is zero, leaving us the answer that

$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}\mathrm{d}t=0$$

## 2. Laplace transform

Since we are integrating this function from zero to infinity, we can find its Laplace transform first, and then evaluate the formula at $s=0$. Basically, we construct the following function:

$$
F(s)=\int_0^\infty{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
$$

Now, let's use Feynman's trick to eliminate the denominator:

$$
F'(s)=\int_0^\infty{\partial\over\partial s}{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^\infty(\cos(t)-e^{-t})e^{-st}\mathrm{d}t
=\mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)-e^{-st}\}
$$

Due to the linearity of Laplace transform operator, we can split the integrand, and using table of Laplace transform allows us to quickly find its answer:

$$
F'(s)=\mathcal{L}\{\cos(t)\}-\mathcal{L}\{e^{-t}\}
={s\over s^2+1}-{1\over s+1}
$$

Now, we have found a convenient expression for $F'(s)$ to work with, so let's find its antiderivative $F(s)$:

$$
F(s)=\int\left[{s\over s^2+1}-{1\over s+1}\right]\mathrm{d}s
={1\over2}\ln|s^2+1|-\ln|s+1|+C=\ln\left|\sqrt{s^2+1}\over s+1\right|+C
$$

Recall the integral definition of $F(s)$, we know that the integral goes to zero as $s\to\infty$, so

$$
\lim_{s\to\infty}\ln\left|\sqrt{s^2+1}\over s+1\right|+C=C
\Rightarrow C=0
$$

As a result, we know $F(s)=\ln\left|\sqrt{s^2+1}\over s+1\right|$. If we set $s=0$, we can also find the same answer that the integral equals to zero:

$$
\int_0^\infty{e^{-t}-\cos(t)\over t}\mathrm{d}x=F(0)=\ln(1)=0
$$

## 3. Special functions (incomplete, I asked Wolfram Alpha for help)

To prevent dealing with nasty divergence problems, we split the integrands:

$$
\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-1\over x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^\infty{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x
$$

By **dominated convergence theorem**, we can show that

$$
\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-1\over x}\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n{\left(1-{x\over n}\right)^n-1\over x}\mathrm{d}x\equiv\lim_{n\to\infty}I_1
$$

It is also not difficult to show that the original integral is equivalent to:

$$
\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(I_1+\underbrace{\int_0^n{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x}_\text{We will call it $I_2$ later}\right)
$$

If we were perform substitution $u={1-x\over n}$ and $-n\mathrm{d}u=\mathrm{d}x$, we can turn this integral into a neat form:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1&=-\int_0^1{1-u^n\over1-u}\mathrm{d}u \\
&=-\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u^k\mathrm{d}u \\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1u^k\mathrm{d}u \\
&=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{1\over k+1}\equiv -H_n
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, let's look at $I_2$. To prevent divergence, let's also split it:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2&=\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^n{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x+\ln(n)-\int_1^n{\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, if we go back to the original integral, we found

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[-(H_n-\ln(n))+\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x-\int_1^n{\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x\right] \\
&=-\gamma+\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x-\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\int_1^n{\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x\right] \\
&=-\gamma+\mathrm{Ci}(1)+\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$

Due to my limited math ability, I ask Wolfram Alpha for help, and it turns out that the remaining integral $\int_0^1{1-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x$ is exactly $\gamma-\mathrm{Ci}(1)$. As a result, the answer is exactly zero.

$$
\int_0^\infty{e^{-x}-\cos(x)\over x}\mathrm{d}x=-\gamma+\mathrm{Ci}(1)+\gamma-\mathrm{Ci}(1)=0
$$

P.S. I will update this as long as I can figure it out without the help of any answer engines

Comment: (+1) The Laplace method as described in the posting is not quite correct unless one knows that the integral itself converges (either in the sense or Lebesgue or as an improper Riemann integral ). For example $\int^\infty_0e^{-at}\cos t\,dt=\frac{a}{a^2+1}\xrightarrow{a\rightarrow0}0$; however $\int^\infty_0\cos x\,dx$ is not convergent.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I didn't learn much analysis when I was writing the answer, but I do admit there is indeed a need to check convergence before plugging in the parameters. The integral, in fact, does converge improperly in the sense of Riemann, which can be verified by an integration by parts.